# Is there a way to send variables through RTC in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, jsfiddle, channel

I am working on a project to make a three.js multiplayer game. I finished the basics and all I need to do now is to add the multiplayer part. I figured out that there was this thing called RTC I could use without making a server complicatedly. All I need to do is send a player position's variables through the channel so a random player can see another player's character. I am kind of struggling, so is there anyone out there that can help me complete this separate code? Thank you! Also I am using JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Plain_Gamer/cqvh78dr/22/

```js
function startup() {
  connectButton = document.getElementById('connectButton');
  disconnectButton = document.getElementById('disconnectButton');
  sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
  messageInputBox = document.getElementById('message');
  receiveBox = document.getElementById('receivebox');

  connectButton.addEventListener('click', connectPeers, false);
  disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', disconnectPeers, false);
  sendButton.addEventListener('click', sendMessage, false);
}

localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

sendChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel(prompt('Create channel name...'));
remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(prompt('Enter channel name...'));
remoteConnection.ondatachannel = RTCRtpReceiver;
```

```html
<button id="connectButton" name="connectButton" class="buttonleft">
  Connect
</button>
<button id="disconnectButton" name="disconnectButton" class="buttonright" disabled>
  Disconnect
</button>
<div class="messagebox">
  <label for="message">Enter a message:
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message text" inputmode="latin" size=60 maxlength=120 disabled>
  </label>
  <button id="sendButton" name="sendButton" class="buttonright" disabled>
    Send
  </button>
</div>
<div class="messagebox" id="receivebox">
  <p>Messages received:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am by no means a WebRTC expert, I know it can send strings (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/send#Example)). I think the best way to accomplish your goal is to convert the variables to an object, and convert the object to a string that can be sent. Then, on the other end, you can decode the string and get the data. Here's a demonstration (without WebRTC).

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

// Convert variables x and y into an object
let obj = { x, y };

// Turn the object to a string
let str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str):

// Turn the string back into the object
let decodedObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(decodedObj);
```

Comment: I think this could work due to the fact that you can't send literal variables through the RTC channels, you could possibly be able to send strings and objects. Thank you very much, this was helpful.

Comment: You can send a string--see the link I added to my answer.

Comment: I got banned for making a question that said bull et. It was about asking how to clone a div to have it be used as am mo. So I will change that question, can you view the new one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345449/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-number-keep-adding-up-so-that-in-the-future-it-doesnt